# Tensor.eval() Performance Decay

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, tensorflow

I used Tensorflow 0.6 with Python 3 to train Neural Network on GPU (Nvidia GeForce GTX Titan X), and I noticed that the time consumption for running `tensor.eval(session=..., feed_dict=...)` was continuously growing as training time goes by, which indicated that performance of `tensor.eval()` decayed. I wonder if anyone has any ideas on this problem. Thanks!!!